# Matlab reading hex values from text file with non hex values interspersed?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a text file that looks something like this what's pasted below.  Several hex values followed by "xx" followed by hex values.  The pattern repeats ~1M times.  I'm looking for a good way to read out just the hex values ignoring the "xx" values.  Textscan seems interesting, but doesn't support hex.  fscanf is great, but it chokes as soon as it hits the first "xx" in the file.  I wrote a clunky script, which reads everything as a string, omits "xx"s and uses dec2hex, but this is *painfully* slow (obviously).  Any suggestions?

```
7F
55
8A
9B
6E
XX
XX
XX
XX
FF
DE
BE
EF
XX
XX
XX
04
88
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution reads 1 million 2-character lines in less than a second on my laptop:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
A   = textscan(fid,'%2c','CommentStyle','XX');
fclose(fid);
A   = hex2dec(A{:});
```

Note the `'CommentStyle'` option that skips those lines that start with XX.